# What are the advantages or disadvantages of declaring function/method in companion objects versus declaring them in traits?

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and I now started a project in Scala and I see similar to the following construct:

```
trait SomeTrait extends SomeOtherStuff with SomeOtherStuff2 

object SomeTrait {
   def someFunction():Unit = { ??? } 
}
```

I understand that for a class, companion objects hold methods that are used in a "static", like Factory methods in Java or something alike, but what about traits, why not put these methods in traits?

Comment: For the same reason. That function is like a `satatic`. On **Scala** you would simply think that apart from the `trait` _SomeTrait_, there is also an `object` _(a `value`)_ also caled _SomeTrait_, which has the _someFunction_ `function`. If that is useful or not, or makes sense or not, for your use case, is something only you can answer.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez but taits are not instantiated like classes so why not put "static" methods on traits, something like default methods on Java8+ interfaces.

Comment: When you create a class that extends / implements the **trait** then all those methods will be added to the instance, like if they were defined in the class. The same applies to **Java 8** interfaces. - The point here is that if you move _someFunction_ to the trait, then all instance _(subclasses / subtypes)_ of that will have the method. Whereas if it is in the companion object, then it just exists in the _SomeTrait_ `object`.

Comment: Of course trait methods are "instantiated".

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I think this should be an answer, not comments.

Comment: @AlexyRomanov most of the time I am on a cellphone. Writing answers on a cellphone is really difficult and tedious _(specially for including code)_. That means that I really can not provide a complete answer with the appropriate quality. Thus I just leave a comment with the essential content. If you feel that should be an answer, feel free to copy and paste it & complement it.

Answer (score 2):

The first style is called `mixin`, it used to be somewhat popular back in the days.

It could be replaced by the following code:

```
object SomeOtherStuff {
   def someMethod(): String
}

object SomeObj {
  import SomeOtherStuff._

  //now someMethod is available
  def otherMethod(): String = someMethod + "!"
}

object Caller {
  import SomeObj._
  import SomeOtherStuff._

  //utility methods from both objects are available here
}
```

Pros of mixins:

If `SomeTrait` extends 10 other mixins then extending this trait would allow to scrap 10 `import` statements

Cons of mixins:

1) creates unnecessary coupling between traits

2) awkward to use if the caller doesn't extend the mixin itself

Avoiding mixins for business-logic code is a safe choice.

Although I'm aware of 2 legitimate usecases:

1) importing DSLs
e.g. ScalaTest code :

`class SomeSuite extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfter {...}`

2) working (as a library author) with implicit parameters:
e.g. `object Clock extends LowPriorityImplicits`

(https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/master/core/shared/src/main/scala/cats/effect/Clock.scala#L127)

Answer (score 1):

Another perspective to this is the OOP principle Composition Over Inheritance.

Pros of **companion objects (composition)**:

- **composition can be done at runtime while traits are defined at compile time**
- **you can easily have multiple of them**. You don't have to deal with the quirks of multiple inheritance: say you have two traits that both have a method with the name `foo` - which one is going to be used or does it work at all? For me, it's easier to see the delegation of a method call, multiple inheritance tends to become complex very fast because you lose track where a method was actually defined

Pros of **traits (mixins)**:

- mixins seem more idiomatic to reuse, a class using a companion object of another class is odd. You can create standalone objects though.
- it's cool for frameworks because it adds the frameworks functionality to your class without much effort. Something like that just isn't possible with companion objects.

In doubt, I prefer companion objects, but it always depends on your environment.